# Slow Response on Read/Delete Query on a Table with Composite Key - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns and a composite primary key, example below:

> ### TABLE_X
>
> ColumnA BIGINT,
>   ColumnB BIGINT,
>   ColumnC BIGINT,
>   ColumnD Float
>
> PRIMARY KEY (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
>   INDEX (ColumnA, ColumnB)
>   INDEX (ColumnA)

This table contains around 2,000,000 records. When i am using a query to read records, system is using 10+ minutes to return the response.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE ColumnA='X'
```

The case with DELETE is worst, no response is returned, the system keeps on executing the query.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_X WHERE ColumnA='X'
```

I am converting my application from MySQL to SQL Server with PHP. It is working perfectly fine on MySQL but on MS SQL Server 2017 this query is taking too much time.

I have tested it on a proper Server Machine with 64GB RAM and on a SQL Server installed within VMWare, no difference in response.

I would like to inquire on how to fix this issue as in future there will be lot more records in this table. Same issue with few other tables where composite key exists.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The more indexes you have on a table, the slower a DML statement will be, however, it will (often) benefit a wider range clauses for `SELECT` statements; Indexes can very often be a double edged sword. I *suspect* the real problem here is that your Primary Key is `CLUSTERED`, but isn't always ascending; so is become fragmented, but also constantly needing to be reordered. True DDL statements for your objects (table and indexes) and your query plans (use PasteThePlan) will help us far more.

Comment: What we don't do is guess based on some pseudo-code DDL. Post the actual DDL for the table involved and the actual query you use to evaluate the issue. Note that 'X' is a string literal but ColumnA is an int - use the appropriate literal format for your column and avoid implicit conversion when possible. And as you select based on a single column which is part of the PK, your query returns many rows. How many of those 2million rows does it return.

Comment: And are you basing your question on the response time measured from your application or from SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the issue by applying the server maintenance & re-building the indexes.